# editing sysctl.conf on oracle linux 7.5

Tags: linux, vi, sysctl, oracle

I am going to install oracle database 12c on oracle linux 7.5. In the process, I have to edit following kernel parameters and set values.

```
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 536870912
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default = 262144
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 262144
net.core.wmem_max = 1048586
```

Documentation says I should edit /etc/sysctl.conf file. 
When I run cat /etc/sysctl.conf to read current contents it displays following message.

```
# sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.    
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5)
```

When I try to edit with root user in vi, it says sysctl.conf is read only. even when I override with '!', changes does not apply and modify the parameters.

Comment: after editing `sysctl.conf`
, changes to the runtime kernel parameters will only be applied after running `sysctl -p` as root/with sudo.

Comment: wow..it worked @RuiFRibeiro. thanks for the valuable reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edits to the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` normally will only affect the system upon reboot *unless* you run by hand:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

If you want to set a particular kernel variable at run time, do:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmni=4096
```

If you want to see all the kernel variables, do:

```
sysctl -a
```